# What's the best way to sort this JSON payload on a particular key using Groovy Script?

Tags: json, sorting, arraylist, groovy, nested

I'm going to be retrieving a JSON payload from a REST API call and I need to return the results sorted on a particular key in the payload. I need to use Groovy to perform the sort. I've written the following that contains a sample of the JSON I need to sort:

```
// Sample JSON body for testing...
def body =
'{\
   "recordSetTotal": 977,\
    "resourceName": "categoryview",\
    "resourceId": "qa-api.acme.com/search/resources/store/10151/categoryview/@top?depthAndLimit=-1,-1,-1,-1&catalogId=12003",\
    "recordSetStartNumber": 0,\
    "recordSetComplete": "true",\
    "catalogGroupView":\
    [\
        {\
            "shortDescription": "For Home",\
            "sequence": "12003_-1_1.00000",\
            "resourceId": "15071",\
            "identifier": "Home"\
        },\
        {\
            "shortDescription": "Accessories",\
            "sequence": "12003_-1_7.00000",\
            "resourceId": "15068",\
            "identifier": "Handbags & Acc"\
        },\
        {\
            "shortDescription": "Juniors",\
            "sequence": "12003_-1_3.00000",\
            "resourceId": "15064",\
            "identifier": "Juniors & Guys"\
        },\
        {\
            "shortDescription": "Kids",\
            "sequence": "12003_-1_4.00000",\
            "resourceId": "15065",\
            "identifier": "Kids"\
        }\
    ]\
}'

// Convert to Groovy Object
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
messageBody = (Map) slurper.parseText(body)
println "*** Original Message ***"
println messageBody
println ""

println messageBody['catalogGroupView']['sequence']
```

I need to sort the catalogGroupView by sequence such that the resulting JSON looks like:

```
// JSON after sort body for testing...
def body =
'{\
   "recordSetTotal": 977,\
    "resourceName": "categoryview",\
    "resourceId": "qa-api.acme.com/search/resources/store/10151/categoryview/@top?depthAndLimit=-1,-1,-1,-1&catalogId=12003",\
    "recordSetStartNumber": 0,\
    "recordSetComplete": "true",\
    "catalogGroupView":\
    [\
        {\
            "shortDescription": "For Home",\
            "sequence": "12003_-1_1.00000",\
            "resourceId": "15071",\
            "identifier": "Home"\
        },\
        {\
            "shortDescription": "Juniors",\
            "sequence": "12003_-1_3.00000",\
            "resourceId": "15064",\
            "identifier": "Juniors & Guys"\
        },\
        {\
            "shortDescription": "Kids",\
            "sequence": "12003_-1_4.00000",\
            "resourceId": "15065",\
            "identifier": "Kids"\
        },\
        {\
            "shortDescription": "Accessories",\
            "sequence": "12003_-1_7.00000",\
            "resourceId": "15068",\
            "identifier": "Handbags & Acc"\
        }\
    ]\
}'
```

I've been experimenting with:

```
        messageBody.sort { a, b -> a.catalogGroupView <=> b.catalogGroupView}
```

But that produces a:

Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: catalogGroupView for class: java.util.TreeMap$Entry

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully sort using the following:

```
messageBody['catalogGroupView'] = messageBody['catalogGroupView'].sort{ a, b -> a.sequence <=> b.sequence}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider the following:

```
messageBody.catalogGroupView = messageBody.catalogGroupView.sort { it.sequence }
```

which uses property notation instead of indexing notation, and natural sort ordering instead of explicit sort ordering.